# Deploying a Jax-WS application locally - HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, http, jboss

I have setup a local server running in eclipse. It is to run my max-ws application which I have been making.

Once the server has started i can proceed to the following directory to view the management console;

```
> http://localhost:8080/
```

The name of my war file is hotornotserver.war - so assuming i deploy the war in the management console i should then be able to proceed to the following directory to view the wsdl.

```
> http://localhost:8080/hotornotserver?wsdl
```

As it stands when i do this i get the following error;

> HTTP Status 404 - /hotornotserver
>
> type Status report
>
> message /hotornotserver
>
> description The requested resource (/hotornotserver) is not available.
>
> JBoss Web/7.0.1.Final

Baically i am interested in finding out how I can call methods on my local web service to perform some analysis on metrics / performance however I keep getting the error above. Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks